# How to login to a MediaWiki site as browser?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to grab the content off an old MediaWiki site by accessing the edit pages. To do this I need to login.  This should mean I will be able to grab the content and markup without any html in the textarea field.

The site doesn't appear to have the api enabled, and it seems to be quite an old version not upgraded since at least 2010.

There is a `wikidb_mw__session` cookie sent when I attempt to do a POST login to

```
/w/index.php?title=Special:Userlogin&action=submitlogin&type=login
```

using `wpName=usrname&wpPassword=userpass&wpLoginattempt=Log+in`

but when I supply this cookie and try to login again using POST
the content returned says I am supplying an incorrect user name.

If I login using the browser instead, I get `wikidb_mw_UserID`, `wikidb_mw_UserName`, and `wikidb_mw_Token` cookies sent back according to live headers.

Just wondering what else it is expecting other then sessions cookies to allow me to login.

Comment: How old is the site? Are you sure it doesn't support the API? Or `Special:Export`? Or `action=raw`?

Comment: It's running php 4.5 or something.  Doesn't respond to API calls ... gives 404 errors. Not sure how to get the mediawiki version.

Comment: Have you looked at `Special:Version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the edit page to export contents is not a great idea. You can use `Special:Export` to get XML.

For example, to export the article about StackOverflow from Wikipedia replace it's URL

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow

with

> [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/**Special:Export**/Stack_Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport/Stack_Overflow)

Comment: Yes, I know about Special:Export but I'd like to avoid removing all the html tables etc that that approach brings.

Comment: @GrahamChiu What tables are you talking about? It gives you exactly the same wiki markup you'll see in the textarea on the Edit page.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I should have looked more closely. The difference I see is that in the edit page, you see html, but in the export view I see html entities.  If that is the case, maybe I can cope with that.  I wasn't expecting to see any html.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Oh right, that's because it's XML, you can't have HTML special symbols in it. The thing is that when you'll get an Edit page it will also contain HTML entities. You see them rendered jus because your browser renders them. Again, what you'll get in `<text>` tag of exported XML is _exactly_ the same as what you have in `<textarea>` on the Edit page.